# Is OpenDaylight supported in Canonical OpenStack as network controller?

Tags: openstack, openstack-autopilot, canonical

We are trying to decide on a proper way to deploy Canonical OpenStack with ODL (via mechanism driver in ML2). Is it possible to get Canonical OpenStack out-of-the-box with ODL?
If not, is there a procedure to add a plugin to the Autopilot/Maas?
Or must we deploy ODL manually (in script)?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't supported.

You would have to put OpenDaylight in via a secondary process of some kind.  There are juju charms for it, they would be a good starting point for how to integrate that into what is deployed by the openstack autopilot:

https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers-next/odl-controller
https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers-next/neutron-api-odl
https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers-next/openvswitch-odl

But, YMMV, of course.